# How do I get the sum of numbers present in a string? 

Tags: xslt, xpath, sum

So I have a XML file and am using XSLT to form HTML page. my title tag in XML includes text followed by `::` followed by a number. I managed to extract the number but I don't know how to sum the numbers.

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(substring-after(/searchresult/document[@id = current()/@refid]/title, ' ::'))/>
```

If I do

```
 <xsl:value-of select=" sum(number(substring-after(/searchresult/document[@id = current()/@refid]/title, ' ::')))>
```

it shows me the following error:

> Error:The value is not a node-set

I even tried making a variable and storing the values in it and tried summing it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="total">     
    <xsl:value-of select="number(substring-after(/searchresult/document[@id = current()/@refid]/title, ' ::'))"/>   
</xsl:variable>     
<xsl:value-of select="($total)"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="sum($total)"/>
```

But it then shows me this error:

> Error:Cannot process a result tree fragment as a node-set under XSLT
>   1.0

How do I get the sum of the numbers I parsed from the title? Please help me...I am lost. I really appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Please show sample input XML. It is not clear to me how your "numbers" appear in the source.

Comment: The second error is given by the improper setting of `xsl:variable`. Use `select` attribute of `xsl:variable`, otherwise the number will be typed to the XSLT 1.0 RTF type. However, it's strange you are performing a sum with a single number.

Comment: @empo - "However, it's strange you are performing a sum with a single number." Yeah, this is why we need the source. I think something is not being communicated here.

Comment: Another reason for needing the source is `/title` in the `substring-after()`; I doubt that `title` is the root element.

Comment: I made changes to the original question so that it makes more sense. I could add the source file but I don't see an attachment button anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to use XML fragments to do stuff like this.

```
<xsl:variable name="Counter">
    <xsl:for-each select="TITLETAG">
        <Number>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(/title, ' ::')"/> 
        </Number>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="sum(number($Counter/*:Number/text()))" />
```

This should give you the solution or at least a head start, assuming of course that there is more than 1 title element. Remember to change TITLETAG to your title element.

Comment: How can there be more than one title element if the OP is using `/title`? There can't be more than one root element.

Comment: Depends on context, and the format of the source. You're assuming that title is the root.

Comment: I only make that assumption based on the use of `/title`. If it was any other context, the `/` wouldn't be used before `title`.

Comment: Good catch, however the solution should at least give him a head start, maybe not a final implementation.

Comment: I made changes to the original question. I thought /title instead of whole thing would give an idea but I was wrong. I have now posted the actual query that I have in my XSLT file.

ScottMcGready- 
<xsl:value-of select="sum(number($Counter/*:Number/text()))" />
 gives an error. It says: Invalid character (:) in expression sum(number($Counter/*:Number/text()))

Answer (score 0):

Your description is confusing because it suggests there is only one title and therefore only one number. Let's assume the numbers are in the nodes selected using //title.

In XSLT 2.0, it's simple:

```
sum(for $x in //title return number(substring-after($x, '::')))
```

In XSLT 1.0 there are three ways of summing a set of numbers that are computed rather than appearing directly in the source. None of them can be described as easy.

(a) use a two-phase transformation. Construct a temporary tree whose nodes contain the numbers, use the xx:node-set() extension to convert this to a node-set, then apply the sum() function to the node-set.

(b) use recursion: write a recursive named template that repeatedly calls itself to process each node and accumulate a total until there are no nodes left to process

(c) use higher-order functions available from Dimitre Novatchev's FXSL library.

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0. I have updated the original question. Hopefully it will make more sense now. Can you tell me how to do it in XSLT 1.0? Thankyou

Comment: I mean can you explain the xx:node-set() more in detail please? Thankyou